# Падеж дательный или родительный

Tags: синтаксис

Они пытались овладеть крепостью Азов, что позволило бы взять под контроль булавинцев низовья Дона.
Вызывает сомнение булавинцев?... булавинцами?!

Answer (score 3):

Место в предложении для **булавинцев** неудачно выбрано. Предлагаю так:

*Они пытались овладеть крепостью Азов, что позволило бы **булавинцам** взять под контроль низовья Дона.*